# @Pattern Hibernate validation

Tags: hibernate, validation, design-patterns

public class DependentDto {
private UUID id;
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"dateOfBirth", "age", "maritalStatus", "bloodGroup", "religion", "aadharNumber", "panCardNumber", "uanNumber", "passportNumber", "permanentAddress", "communicationAddress", "guardianName","nextOfKin","nextOfKinContactNumber","skillSet","employeeDto"})
private PersonalInformationDto personalInformationDto;
@NotNull(message = "Name can not be null")
private String name;
@NotNull(message = "Relation can not be null")
private String relation;
@NotNull(message = "Date Of Birth Date cannot be null")
@Pattern(regexp = "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$", message = "Invalid date format. Please use the format yyyy-MM-dd (e.g., 2007-12-03).")
private String dateOfBirth;
@Pattern(regexp = "^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$", message = "Invalid phone number format")
private String contactNumber;
}

## *This is my DTO class. I have added few pattern validation. When I test this in postman, for wrong pattern I get a very long error message as shown below. Is there a simple way to just show "Invalid date format. Please use the format yyyy-MM-dd (e.g., 2007-12-03).")  instead of the entire message like below*

{
"timestamp": "2024-01-23T10:32:04.470+00:00",
"path": "/dependents",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.frestonanalytics.msl.staffalyze.dto.DependentDto> com.frestonanalytics.msl.staffalyze.controller.DependentController.createDependent(com.frestonanalytics.msl.staffalyze.dto.DependentDto,org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange), with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'dependentDto' on field 'dateOfBirth': rejected value [1990-07-]; codes [Pattern.dependentDto.dateOfBirth,Pattern.dateOfBirth,Pattern.java.lang.String,Pattern]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [dependentDto.dateOfBirth,dateOfBirth]; arguments []; default message [dateOfBirth],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@b9d7349a,^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$]; default message [Your custom error message for dateOfBirth pattern mismatch]] ",
"requestId": "53206fd4-2",
"errors": [
{
"codes": [
"Pattern.dependentDto.dateOfBirth",
"Pattern.dateOfBirth",
"Pattern.java.lang.String",
"Pattern"
],
"arguments": [
{
"codes": [
"dependentDto.dateOfBirth",
"dateOfBirth"
],
"arguments": null,
"defaultMessage": "dateOfBirth",
"code": "dateOfBirth"
},
[],
{
"codes": [
"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"
],
"arguments": null,
"defaultMessage": "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"
}
],
"defaultMessage": "Your custom error message for dateOfBirth pattern mismatch",
"objectName": "dependentDto",
"field": "dateOfBirth",
"rejectedValue": "1990-07-",
"bindingFailure": false,
"code": "Pattern"
}
]
}

Tried ValidationMessages.properties but dint work

Answer (score 0):

I found the required customisation

In Global Exception Handler class, I added a handler shown below

@ExceptionHandler(WebExchangeBindException.class)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>> handleValidationException(WebExchangeBindException ex, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
Map<String, Object> errorResponse = new LinkedHashMap<>();
errorResponse.put("timestamp", Instant.now());
errorResponse.put("path", exchange.getRequest().getPath().value());
errorResponse.put("status", ex.getRawStatusCode());
errorResponse.put("error", ex.getStatus().getReasonPhrase());
errorResponse.put("message", ex.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
errorResponse.put("requestId", exchange.getRequest().getId());
return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorResponse));
}